# Debugging a SIGPIPE signal from third party library

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, signals

I am debugging a significantly large Qt-3 application. The application does a lot of pre-processing and then receives a SIGPIPE signal. I'm writing down few entries of the backtrace as soon as I get SIGPIPE.

```
#0 .. __write_nocancel () from libpthread.so
#1 .. _IceTransFreeConnInfo () from libICE.so.6
#2 .. _IceWrite () from libICE.so.6
#3 .. _IceFlush () from libICE.so.6
```

Our application has a signal handler. What I did was to ignore SIGPIPE using `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)`, thinking that my app will continue even if I get this signal. But now I realize that it will not work that way, it just exists if I continue after receiving SIGPIPE.

I am clueless as how to debug this issue. This signal is not originating from a socket call directly by our app. It is coming from libICE. Am I correct? Please give some hints on how to debug this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: When the app itself `raise()`es the signal, you should be able to catch that in a debugger.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: who said anything about `raise()`?

Answer (score 1):

The signal is coming from the kernel, and is the result of `write(2)`ing to a file descriptor, for which the receiver has either died, or executed a `shutdown(2)`.

It sounds as if something in your code screwed up a file descriptor that belongs to `libICE.so`, and not to you.

Your first step should probably be to run the application under `strace`, and then analyze the log to see exactly how the FD on which `libICE` is writing has been screwed up.

Once you know what is happening, use GDB `catch syscall` command to find out *where* it is happening.